# Apps Filesharing - iTunes - Windows 7 - <file> could not be copied because its name is too long

Tags: itunes, windows, filesystem

I am an app developer and I am trying to help a customer move a file from their iPhone in Document sharing.

They take the following steps:
[image: iTunes Steps]

But receive the following error:

[image: <file> could not be copied because its name is too long or includes characters that are invalid on the destination volume]

(`<file> could not be copied because its name is too long or includes characters that are invalid on the destination volume`)

The longest file name in the folder will be something like: `CoreDataUbiquitySupport/mobile\~B63CA3F9-0971-4F53-AF50-B1F792DDEFFE/iCloudStore/BC2FFBEC-33FA-4157-9F89-5D16429878C1/container/mobile\~B63CA3F9-0971-4F53-AF50-B1F792DDEFFE/iCloudStore/dITgSOv1a\~uXwdg84VBrJ5ksgQRT7WHwf7B9JLbKre8\=` those random strings should all be the same length (232 chars total).

They tell me they are on the latest version of iTunes and Windows 7.

I can't find anything on google for this error.

Any help *hugely* appreciated.

[Apologies if this isn't the best place for this question, suggestions for where is the best place very much welcome. The general Apple Support forums which is where I assumed would be best have told me not to post there..]

Comment: We'd really need to know the filename & full path to be certain, but Acronis has a nice KB on [x-plat illegal chars](https://kb.acronis.com/content/39790), & Apple a [Best x-plat Practices KB](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202808)

Comment: Thanks for this, I've added an example full filename to the question. I guess it's the length that's the problem. I'm not sure at what stage they get the error, but maybe if I get them to save it to C:\ instead of My Documents or wherever it might work.

Comment: I'm wondering how it is handling the escapes \~ \= etc, as the \ itself is an illegal character - or are those for 'our' benefit, as they're not actually needed for human legibility in an SE `code block`

Comment: Thanks for all your help @Tetsujin. This is the path I get on my Mac when connected to the simulator, I'm not sure if the \'s are part of the path or added by terminal. I know terminal would escape a space

Comment: Brief update: my original customer with this problem updated to Windows 10 and that solved it for them. I now have another customer with the same problem though :(

Comment: @Tetsujin the article is not up-to-date, as `:` is nowadays allowed: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/173529/when-did-the-colon-character-become-an-allowed-character-in-the-filesystem