# Saving a filename with a special character in Mac?

Tags: macos, finder, filesystem, path, html

I'm using a MacBook Pro with Catalina 10.15.7 and keyboard is set to UK English.

I made a folder, mytest on Desktop, and the file test.html with CSS.

The character in question is https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+002F

I can use the character in HTML with no problems, but for filenames it's a bit more of a problem.

It's a test file, so not for public viewing or usage and wouldn't be in production files anyway.

I've done some light Google-ing, but would appreciate the help as I'm not sure; the only reason for this is simply to learn a bit more about something that I've learnt in HTML (characters / unicode).

Can I name a file with the unicode solidus with the name test/mytest/2021.html ?

Comment: You can't / is a special character and it means a directory in any API you can call to use  a file name([In HFS+ for confusion / and : are swapped to each other at some level of the system)  Try any other character e.g. U+1F600 

Comment: Or https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+FF0F, to at least make it look like / and confuse the hell out of people. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/183056/9058 for a way to enter Unicode characters.

Comment: I'd caution that trying to use this character is asking for trouble, and that you should find another method of achieving whatever the result is.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unicode U+002F is equivalent to ASCII 47, or the "slash"/soldus key on your keyboard. Calling it a Unicode special character
is a bit like maître Pathelin in the medieval farce discovering that he was speaking prose; it's just the unmodified output of the key next to the right shift key.

It's not so much that it's a *Unicode* special character as that it's a special character in the operating system. MacOS has long had a [complicated relationship](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/173529/when-did-the-colon-character-become-an-allowed-character-in-the-filesystem) with the slash and colon symbols in path names.

In the command line, `/` is treated as the directory separator, and cannot be used in filenames. In the Finder, `:` has been used as the directory separator. A file with a `:` in its name will display as a `/` in the Finder, but may produce problems with some program's name safety checks.

If you type at the terminal prompt `touch ~/Desktop/test:mytest:2021.html`, that file will appear on your desktop as `test/mytest/2021.html`, but not all programs might be happy about it.